# How can I call the contract constructor and send a funding value when deploying with MyEtherWallet?

Tags: myetherwallet

This option doesn't seem to be available on MyEtherWallet. Are constructors unsupported?

Answer (score 2):

There would be two ways of doing that:
- The most obvious is via their `Contracts` tab but that one is missing a field for constructor data.
- The second one would be via a "normal transaction" in the `Send Ether & Tokens` tab. That one would need a (currently not existing) checkbox for indicating that you are deploying a contract. Such a "deploy contract" transaction does not have a `to` field and has a flag set that indicates this as a special "deploy contract" transaction. Therefore, in such cases the `To Address` would need to be removed.

So in summary I do not see that this is currently possible.

Now I'm being picky: Default constructors (without arguments) are supported. MyEtherWallet just doesnt support constructors that do take parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any screens in MyEtherWallet that will allow a user to deploy contracts. The contracts tab in MEW allows you to interact with already deployed contracts.

If you want to deploy contracts, use `geth`, Ethereum Wallet or Parity. If you have issues with the large sync time required for `geth`, use Parity as the client node. You can then connect Remix (Browser Solidity) or Ethereum Wallet to your Parity node.

When deploying using `geth`, Ethereum Wallet, Parity or Remix, you can send a funding value when deploying contracts.